# Icon and splash screen not showing up meteor ios

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

I build an app using Meteor and am trying to get it properly deployed on an iOS device. My problem is although I have included graphics for the app icons and launch screens, they are not showing up when I test the app on my mobile device.

Here is my mobile-config.js file:

```
App.info({
  name: 'petro',
  description: 'petro portal',
  version: '1.0.0'
});

App.icons({
  'iphone': 'public/Portal_Logo_180_180.png',
  'iphone_2x': 'public/Portal_Logo_180_180.png',
  'iphone_3x': 'public/Portal_Logo_180_180.png'
});

App.launchScreens({
  'iphone': 'public/Portal_Logo_1024x1024.png',
  'iphone_2x': 'public/Portal_Logo_1024x1024.png',
  'iphone5': 'public/Portal_Logo_1024x1024.png'
});
```

The steps I take to run my app on device are:

- run `meteor run ios-device`
- click the 'run' button on the xcode window that appears

Has anyone else run into this issue or know a workaround?

Note - the console does not return any errors...

Thanks!

Comment: I believe 'public' is already the root folder for the images. Try removing 'public' from the path.

Comment: hi - that actually throws a 'cannot find file' error...

Comment: I have put those files inside "private/media/splash" and "private/media/icons" which reduces them filling up the appcaqche. That may help.